# looping thorugh array of arrays (hashmap) and squaring numbers (using map function)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

so here is my code (not working) what I want to do is loop through the hashmap and return a new hashmap with squared number so that any hashmap goes into function pow as an argument. and I want to do it in ES6 way.

```
 var numbers = {};
numbers['two'] = [2, 4, 9];
numbers['one'] = [1, 2, 3];
function pow(arr){
 for (var x in arr){
  x.map(function(value)){
    return value*value;
  }
 }
}          
pow(numbers);
```

Comment: When you use `for..in`, your `x` is the ***key***, not the value of the object.

Comment: You have a parameter `arr`, but you're passing in an object ("hashmap") instead of an array.

Comment: Except replacing the function expression with an arrow function, there is nothing you would do differently with ES6.

Comment: Given that you've tagged this ES6, why don't you use a `Map` and `for of` loops?

Answer (score 0):

As Rocket commented above, when using a for...in loop, x is the index, not the actual value. You'll need to use `arr[x]` instead of simply `x` in your loop.

You can use `arr.forEach()` to iterate through an array's values in a more intuitive way, but there are compatibility considerations with that method, so your ability to use it may depend on where you're running the code. (More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).) However, in this case, as Lucas pointed out in the comments, you're passing in an object, not an array, so `forEach()` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you are looking for...as previously stated x in the for loop is the index. You would use arr[x] to get the array such as numbers['one']. You have to redefine the arr[x] with the new map you return. This does the trick. In ES6 you could destructure and then loop through. Feel free to ask for that if you'd like.

```
function pow(hm) {
    for (var x in arr) {
        hm[x] = hm[x].map(function(value) {
            return value*value;
        });
    }

    return hm;
}
```

Comment: OP said "*return a **new** hashmap*", so don't assign to `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

ok I solved it  `

```
var numbers = {};
 numbers['one'] = [2, 4, 9];
 numbers['two'] = [1, 6, 8];
function pow(arr) {

     var arr1 = arr.map(function(value) {
          return value*value;
        });
    return arr1;
  }
console.log(pow(numbers['two']));
pow(numbers['two']);
```

`   this is what I want - it's here http://jsbin.com/bicamimifi/edit?js,console,output